# com.ibm.designer.domino.napi classes missing from import in java class in xpages

Tags: java, xpages

For a project I am using the napi classes to read properties files as described in this post:

http://hasselba.ch/blog/?p=1763

I have created a class as described but after making changes somewhere in my application (by me or a colleague ) and I am rebuilding the project I get message that the following classes were not successfully imported:

```
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesAPIException;
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesDatabase;
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesNote;
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesObject;
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.NotesSession;
import com.ibm.designer.domino.napi.design.FileAccess;
```

As described in the post I perform a project fixup.

But now I have to follow these steps with every new build of the project.

How can I avoid this?